# Printing Log in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, uitextview, performselector

I need to show log outputs in a textview then and there in my app. I tried using **performSelector** inside my sequence but it did not work as I thought it would. Can someone show me how to do it?

For example, when I click a button, I do lot of operations underneath, and I want to display the logs in the textview then and there, not after the entire operation is done.

Plus can't I call **performSelector** more than once inside the same sequence?

> Below is the sequence inside the button click:

```
- (IBAction)Write:(id)sender {

 //do some action here
 DisplayString = @"Seq1 pass"
 [self performSelector:@selector(updateviewText) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
 //do some more action
 DisplayString = @"Seq2 pass"
 [self performSelector:@selector(updateviewText) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
 ....
}
```

> This the updateviewText part:

```
-(void)updateviewText {
        dispatch_queue_t queueNew = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
        dispatch_async(queueNew,^ {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [self.txtViewUseCaseLOG setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", 
                                       self.txtViewUseCaseLOG.text,DisplayString ]];             
        });           
    });
}
```

> The **DisplayString** is a global variable here.
>
> This code doesn't setText to the textview then and there... But as I asked earlier I need those messages then and there...

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the UI asynchronously. If you're doing task asynchronously and want to update the UI you have to use `dispatch_sync`.

And why would you when you're doing something asynchronously open another asynchronous task?

Next thing is that if you're only using `DisplayString` in these two methods you might better add a NSString parameter to `updateViewText` so you don't need the global variable.